# How do I export my prediction(array) in the azure databricks?

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, azure-databricks

I can not export my dataframe to csv. The message "CSV data source does not support array"

predictions.write.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("/mnt/classification2018/testpredic2")

I tried this command but concated, but not sucess

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws

predictions.withColumn("probability", concat_ws(",", "probability")).show()
```

Log Error

```
/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1472.csv.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support array<string> data type.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$CSVUtils$$verifyType$1(CSVUtils.scala:127)
```

Comment: You should not pictures if you can avoid it. Paste the actual data, log, code.

Comment: Sorry, removed picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the column to string and write to csv

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
predictions = predictions.withColumn("probability", col("probability").cast("string))
predictions.write.option("delimiter", "\t").csv("/mnt/classification2018/testpredic2")
```

Comment: The same message "CSV data source does not support array"

Comment: I am able to write the csv without any error. Can you confirm you copied the code shown in the answer. Also, do you have any other array column? Good idea to update your question with your update code and also show the output of `predictions.show(2)` before you write to csv.

Comment: Manoj, sorry for the delay, it was a holiday in my city. I was able to solve it, there was another array column that I forgot to convert. Again thank you very much for the help